# MVC5 caching caches user's session, how can I prevent this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

When I add a cache attribute to a controller's ActionResult, like this:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Hour")]
```

and the profile in the Web.config:

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="Cache1Hour" duration="3600" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>      
</caching>
```

it caches the user's session with the page so because the site shows the user's name in the top right corner, it displays the cached user instead of the current user. **How can I prevent this?** I don't have this issue on MVC 3 websites.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `varyByHeader="*"` to the cache profile in the Web.config seems to work because the header contains the session cookie although this will cause it to cache a page for each user, possibly causing cache overflow.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.outputcacheprofile.varybyheader(v=vs.110).aspx

Another option may be to use the Caching Multiple Versions of User Control Output
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4he1ds5(v=vs.110).aspx